# How To Create A Java Client For A Tensorflow Model Server

Tags: java, tensorflow, grpc, tensorflow-serving, grpc-java

So far I have managed to export a Tensorflow model and then serve that model using the Tensorflow model server.  I have then been able to make predictions by creating a client which talks to the Tensorflow server over gRPC.

Basically I've followed this [tutorial](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic)

This has all been done in Python so far which is fine but I need to be able to call the Tensorflow server using Java.  In other words, I need to create a Java client.

My basic understanding is that I need to compile .proto files into Java classes using the Protoc compiler but I'm not sure how to generate .proto files for my model.  I've exported the model but the files are in the ".pb" format and don't seem to compile to Java classes.

Has anyone had any experience of doing this?  If you have, please kindly share your solution.

Many thanks,

Barry

Answer (score 0):

`.pb` seems to be the serialized protobuf data. Protobuf definitions are `.proto` files which I guess are somewhere downloadable from the TensorFlow project rather than generated from the model.